# IIS Express: startMode=”AlwaysRunning”

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-express

it seems that IIS Express does not support the startMode property in the applicationHost.config ( IIS Express won't start if the startMode prperty is set )

```
<applicationPools>
   <add name=”MyAppPool” startMode=”AlwaysRunning” />
</applicationPools>
```

Am i missing sth. here or is this just not supported?

Thx.

Comment: For anyone looking for applicationHost.config = %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are correct... 'startMode' property is not respected in IIS Express.

Comment: Extra note that most of application pool settings are not honored.

Comment: That is bad because because I was testing Application Initialisation feature for .net 4.5. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series